# run script form .bashrc only once

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi2

I want a python script to be executed at bootup on my raspberry pi2, so I put it into .bashrc.
[Launching the script with crontab](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/step4/Add-to-your-crontab/) didn't work.

But I only want to execute it once. Not everytime I enter a terminal or every time I login via ssh.
My poor try of course didn't work and it's obvious why.

```
python_running=false
if [ "$python_running" = false ] ; then
  ./launcher.sh
  $python_running = true
fi
```

EDIT:
My main problem is that the python script needs internet access. The connection has to be established before the script is executed.
After the first answer and comments I realized that .bashrc is not a good place for launching the script at bootup. It works with autologin, but is not a proper solution.
But what could be a proper solution to run the script only once?

Comment: `.bashrc` is for non-login interactive shells; `.bash_profile` is for login shells.

Comment: What init system is this running? Can you require the networking component? Can the script wait/poll for a connection if one doesn't exist yet?

Comment: @Eta Reisner: I like the idea of polling for connection, but I don't know how to do that in a shell script.

Comment: Polling is the worse option of the bunch, using the init system to schedule yourself after the network is better if possible, but barring that you just need to check for a local IP address, or check that you can resolve the remote address you need, etc. Pick something and test for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.bashrc is definetly not a proper place to do that. To start the script at bootup the best and easiest solution I found is crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then add the following line to the end of the file:

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/launcher.sh > /home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

But to use crontab the shell script needs to be changed to wait/poll for internet connection:

```
ROUTER_IP=192.168.0.1
while ( ! ping -c1 $ROUTER_IP) do
  echo "network is not up yet"
  sleep 3
done
echo "network is up now"
python3 myScript.py &
```

Polling might not be the best option, but there's nothing wrong in creating one sleep process every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. so we need to clarify some terminology ..

The pi (or any unix system) doesn't really distinguish between a "console" login or a ssh (remote) login, it's going to drop you into a shell anyway.

However, if you want something to start on bootup (which is what I think you want), then look at `/etc/rc.d` - [have a look here](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/run-a-script-on-start-up.html) -  but in case that link goes, put a command in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: what I tried is mentioned in the link and why it failed is mentioned in the question: The internet connection needs to be established first.

Comment: And is the internet connection established at bootup or login ? If login, how does the connection get initiated?